# Filter assemblies/namespaces out of Visual Studio 2005 Documentation index

Tags: .net, visual-studio, documentation

Is there any way to remove certain assemblies or namespaces from the index of (or entirely from) the Visual Studio 2005 Documentation? System.Web.UI and System.Windows.Forms contain many identical class names and I'd like to eliminate those in System.Web.UI that are irrelevant to me.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the Visual Studio 2005 Combined Help Collection Manager.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have nothing to remove from the list in Combined Help Collection Manager -- of the 32 items listed, only one is checked (DirectX 9.0). With items like MS.RIBBON.12.1033, MS.EXCEL.12.1033, and MS.OUTLOOK.12.1033 in the list, get the impression that the entire .NET framework is part of the same help "collection."

Answer (score 0):

I always use the online documentation because you can filter and search: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms269115(VS.80).aspx